# Move Image Between Two Vectors

Tags: c#, graphics, draw, win2d

So I'd like to have an image that moves along the white line in the attached screenshot.  But I'm not sure on how to make this happen. Here are my example 
coordinates:

141,78 and 509,223

I draw a line to visualize the path and ultimately I want to move an image from the start to the finish over a period of time. Let's say 5 minutes.

I've been searching the internet for the last 18 hours and I'm still stuck. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: How about using event Paint with e.Graphics.DrawImage. For the animation, use Timer. Change the coordinate and Refresh();.

Comment: The keyword is linear interpolation. One simple form is `x = x2 * a + x1 * (1 - a)` where a goes from 0 to 1.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: You would calculate the longer  distance vector dx or dy; then decide a sensible Timer.Interval (15>i>15000) and finally calculate a float deltaX and float deltaY accordingly. In the Tick add the deltas to the location. You have  a choice of moving the image in a PictureBox or drawing it in the Paint event.

Comment: Edit your question as you are moving an image _along_ a vector and _between_ two points.

Comment: Linear interpolation looks like what I am looking for. 

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23430/get-points-on-a-line-between-two-points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a game loop and something the executes code at fixed intervals. If this is the only animation you want to do then a simpler timer component can trigger the code that updates the location, let say 50 times a second (`Interval=20 ms`).

Here is some skeleton code of an image going around in a circle as drawn on top of an empty `PictureBox`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    float t = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = Resources.Image1;
        float dx = img.Width, dy = img.Height;
        float r = 100;
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height / 2);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        // draw a gray circle to indicate the path visually
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Gray, -r, -r, 2 * r, 2 * r);

        // you must set the x,y coordinate of the center of the image
        // according to your path.
        // If it is a line use linear interpolation
        // x = x_start + t*(x_end-x_start);
        // y = y_start + t*(y_end-y_start);
        float x = (float)(r * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * t));
        float y = -(float)(r * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * t));

        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(img, (int)(x - dx / 2), (int)(y - dy / 2));
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (t >= 1)
        {
            t -= 1;
        }
        t += 0.02f;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 20;
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

[image: scr]

Comment: I need to extrapolate the coordinates from point A to Point B... so the image can be drawn... I think the linear interpolation is the answer.

Comment: Look in the comments of the code. I have the linear interpolation commented out.

Comment: As a note the animation parameter `t` goes from 0 to 1.

Comment: thanks for your help with this. Maybe you could help me with this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427535/how-to-pull-missile-images-on-top-of-the-lines?noredirect=1#comment64267212_38427535