# How to pull missile images on top of the lines?

Tags: c#, graphics, uwp, offset, win2d

As you can see below, the images of the little missiles are not over the lines. 
How can I create an offset that respects the angle and rotation. I am using linear interpolation to extract x y coordinates between the ends of each straight line.

```
            float xDiff = end_xpos[i] - start_xpos[i];
            float yDiff = end_ypos[i] - start_ypos[i];
            double degrees = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
            double radians = (Math.PI / 180) * degrees;


            args.DrawingSession.DrawLine(start_xpos[i], start_ypos[i], end_xpos[i], end_ypos[i], Color.FromArgb(Alpha_line, 255, 255, 255), 2);

            pointX = Math.Round((start_xpos[i] + (end_xpos[i] - start_xpos[i]) * percent), 1);
            pointY = Math.Round((start_ypos[i] + (end_ypos[i] - start_ypos[i]) * percent), 1);

            Missle_ROT.TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)radians);
            args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(Missle_ROT, Convert.ToSingle(pointX), Convert.ToSingle(pointY));
```

[image]

Comment: and where is the missile sprite? and coordinate system description ?

Comment: Is positive rotation clockwise (windows default), or counterclockwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set the angle of your image like this `Missle_ROT.TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)radians);`.

The coordinate system is like this:

[image]

So when you used [Matrix3x2.CreateRotation Method (Single)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn889081(v=vs.111).aspx) to rotate the image, it rotated with the default center point which is also the left-top point of this image. As a solution you can use [Matrix3x2.CreateRotation Method (Single, Vector2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn889085%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to specify the rotation center, and for your scenario, this center should possible be the center of your image. You can have a test like this:

```
var image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Assets/solidimg.png");
var transform = new Transform2DEffect() { Source = image };
//draw image's left-top point (0,0) of the image
args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(new Vector2(200, 200), 10, Colors.Black);
//draw image with no trasform effect
transform.TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation(0);
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(transform, 200, 200);
//draw image with trasform effect and center on the (0,0) point
transform.TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)(20 * Math.PI) / 180);
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(transform, 200, 200);
//draw image's center point of the image
args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(new Vector2((float)(200 + image.Size.Width / 2), (float)(200 + image.Size.Height / 2)), 10, Colors.Red);
//draw image with trasform effect and center on the image's center
transform.TransformMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)(20 * Math.PI) / 180, new Vector2((float)image.Size.Width / 2, (float)image.Size.Height / 2));
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(transform, 200, 200);
```

And for your last code to draw image `args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(Missle_ROT, Convert.ToSingle(pointX), Convert.ToSingle(pointY));`, it still draw the image from the the (0,0) point, you should also calculate the center point of the image to the "pointX" and "pointY" like this:

```
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(Missle_ROT, Convert.ToSingle(pointX- (float)image.Size.Width / 2), Convert.ToSingle(pointY- (float)image.Size.Height / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to draw an image (of dimensions `w`,`h` in pixels) on the screen, rotated with the center at specified pixel coordinates `px` and `py`. You need to find the location of the upper left corner of the image (with coordinates `x_A` and `y_A`).

This is done with a coordinate rotation of the relative location of the image center (`h/2` and `w/2`).

```
x_A = px - (w/2)*cos(θ) + (h/2)*sin(θ)
y_A = py - (w/2)*sin(θ) - (h/2)*cos(θ)
```

[image: fig]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not sure what this symbol means "θ". Is that radians?

Comment: θ is the rotation angle of the missile from horizontal. When used in `sin` or `cos` functions the value must be in radians, but in your program you might keep track of it in degrees. It is up to you.

Comment: Always remember the Greek alphabet: α β γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ σ τ υ φ χ ψ ω